# Order By Sums, while not grouping like rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, sql-order-by

Suppose I have data that looks like this as the result of a query

```
SKU   |  STOCK  |  SNACK  |  FLAVOR 
1234       45       Chips     BBQ
1236       87       Chips     BBQ
2345       12       Pretzel   Bacon
3456       51       Chips     Ranch
4567       32       Pretzel   Classic
5678      142       Candy     Chocolate
...       ...       ...       ...
```

---

Is it possible to have SQL in an `ORDER BY` line that allows me to display the above data first sorted by whatever Snack (Chips, Pretzel, Candy, etc.) has the largest `SUM(Stock)` and then by `Stock DESC` while not merging any of the entries? I briefly tried to use a line similar to

```
 ORDER BY 
 SUM(Snack) DESC,
 SUM(Flavor) DESC,
 Stock DESC
```

but could not determine how the `GROUP BY` statement should be laid out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DSum` to compute total *STOCK* for each *SNACK* without a `GROUP BY`.  And use that `Dsum` in the `ORDER BY`.  I also needed to use `Val()` on the `DSum` values to make it sort correctly.

```sql
SELECT y.SKU, y.STOCK, y.SNACK, y.FLAVOR
FROM YourTable AS y
ORDER BY
    Val(DSum("[STOCK]", "YourTable", "[SNACK]='" & y.SNACK & "'")) DESC,
    y.STOCK DESC;
```

Be aware that `DSum` is Access-specific so this is not suitable if you want a query which can be ported to another database.

Comment: I tracked the problem down. A few of the possible values for Offer_Size are listed in inches, using the " as a notifier of inches. The quotation mark altered the `DSum` code a bit. The comment about the datatype of the field tipped me off.

Thank you again for your help, again!

Answer (score 1):

Try with following SQL

```
select sku, stock, data.snack, flavor, summ = summ.summ  
from data
join (select snack, summ = sum(stock) from data group by snack) as summ
on summ.snack = data.snack
order by summ desc, stock desc

SKU|STOCK|SNACK|FLAVOR|SUMM
1236 87 Chips BBQ 183 
3456 51 Chips Ranch 183 
1234 45 Chips BBQ 183 
5678 142 Candy Chocolate 142 
4567 32 Pretzel Classic 44 
2345 12 Pretzel Bacon 44
```